# Replace commas with colons and move  all values to one line

Tags: bash

I entered a list of number in Calc and saved it as CSV so that all the values on one line are separated by commas. I will describe what I'm seeking with bash in the following example:

**INPUT**

```
22,33
45,533
```

**OUTPUT**

```
22:33,45:533
```

Comment: To better understand the question, add an example input and output, please.

Comment: @enzotib Done. And this time chose the correct CSV, so the input I described before was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but for the input and output you shown, the following `sed` command can do the transformation, taking into account that your input file contains CR-LF line terminators:

```
sed 's/,/:/g;s/ /,/g' <<<$(tr -d '\r' <input_file) | tee output_file.tmp
mv output_file.tmp input_file
```

Comment: `$ sed 's/,/:/g;s/ /,/g' <<<$(<z1.csv)` [new line]
`,50:239`

Comment: The terminal outputs only the last line of the CSV file which was `50,239`. There's no new output file and the original file isn't changed either.

Comment: With the input file you gave in the question, my tests show that it works perfectly. It is probable the your real input file has some particularity not shown in the example input file, and I cannot say what without seeing it. Regarding the modification of the input file, you didn't specified your request in the question, it can be easily done with some additional instruction.

Comment: It doesn't matter how the result is visible to me, but even if the command worked properly, it did not show the complete results in the terminal. [Here](http://pastebin.com/zjvaYnvN)'s the entirety of the file used.

Comment: @Oxwivi: see modified answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution without external binaries - but a slower one (reads line by line and changes '**,**' → '**:**')

```
while read -u 3 -r line; do 
        echo -n "${line/,/:}," >> new_file
done 3< old_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Inefficient, but sure to work:

Open up the file in gedit. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. In find, type `,` and in replace, type `:`. Then select Replace All.

Next, bring up the Find and Replace screen again. In the Find box, type `\n` and leave the Replace box empty. Then select Replace All.

That's it :)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know how to express new lines (`\n`). And not quite inefficient if there's 'replace all' function. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
cat test| sed s/,/:/g | sed s/$/,/g | xargs
```

But produces:

```
22:33, 45:533,
```

So you may have to use this longer version to get the exact result you asked for:

```
cat test| sed s/,/:/g | sed s/$/,/g | xargs | sed "s/, /,/g"
```

I am pretty sure there are better ways of doing this with sed/awk, though this does achieve what you ask for and is pretty easy to read.

Comment: `$ cat z1.csv | sed s/,/:/g | sed s/$/,/g | xargs | sed "s/, /,/g"` [new line]
`,50:239`

Comment: The terminal outputs only the last line of the CSV file which was `50,239`. There's no new output file and the original file isn't changed either.

Comment: So you want your modifications to happen in place, which you did not specify in the question (only "input" and "output").

Comment: Well, I don't mind if the original file was modified, but the output on the terminal only displayed the last line, not everything.

Comment: Then there's something strange with your initial data too. Probably needs crlf conversion.